# How to assign uninstallation password, When we are uninstalling the application

Tags: android

Please suggest me where i can put my uninstallation password code in android application.
So that at the time of uninstall the application ,The application manager should ask me to insert password to uninstall the application.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Removing an app is a built-in feature in Android, and quite frankly I would be quite upset if an app would not easily let me remove it.

I understand that you have a security app in mind, but those kind of things would need to happen on the operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can implement something like App Lock(http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-cc-applock-CtBE.aspx),
which checks if **com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity** is being started.