# Android application security

Tags: android, android-emulator, uninstallation, device-admin

Im developing a parental app which restricts outgoing calls to limited defined numbers.

I need to set a password for the app log in and is it possible to set a password which can be set to control the process of uninstall of this application.

I had gone through some of the links,but haven't reached in any conclusion.

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947847/how-to-assign-uninstallation-password-when-we-are-uninstalling-the-application)

[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221534/require-a-password-to-uninstall-remove-application)

These cannot serve my purpose... that's also not a solution.

Can anybody tell how exactly to add a watcher to serve this purpose?

Comment: How did you **not** draw a conclusion from CommonsWare's (rather clear) answer regarding password-protecting the uninstall: _"That is not possible in Android without firmware modifications."_

Comment: I have seen what i asked in one app.......but unfortunately,cant find that app again in PlayStore......I have also checked other security apps.....any options pleaseeeeeeeeee

Comment: I don't know, maybe if you used a few more `e`s, I might be convinced to help...

Comment: I understand that there are a couple possible use cases for this, but at this time, I believe it is not possible to do this.

Comment: @MattBall sure........will search out the app details.......keep looking a solution please....and it could be useful for many developers as well.......thanksssss

Comment: @michael_andmaf can u specify some of the use cases handled at present?

Comment: I was just saying that I can see a couple of possible use cases for this functionality, enterprise applications maybe, parental control applications, etc, but as I (and others) have mentioned, it currently isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to set a password which can be set to control the process of uninstall of this application.

You are welcome to create your own custom firmware that contains your application, and install that firmware on whatever devices you are allowed to. Your application then cannot be uninstalled.

Android SDK applications cannot "control the process of uninstall".